# Fastest way of reading a text file

Tags: java, string, performance, file-io, text-files

Which is the fastest way of reading a text file?  Do new features of 1.7 offer any functionality in which we can read the text file faster?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964332/java-large-files-disk-io-performance https://blogs.oracle.com/slc/entry/javanio_vs_javaio

Comment: http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly

Comment: umm, current version of Java is 7(1.7)...anyways, try not to worry what is the "fastest" way, especially if you are just beginning to learn this stuff. Trying to optimize programs often just ends up making the program slower because you're adding code.

Comment: *"When seeking to improve performance: prototype and measure first, optimize only if needed."*  From the pop-up of the [tag:performance] tag.  ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220052/regarding-reading-a-file-and-optimizing-the-performance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225297/faster-than-buffered-reader

Comment: You can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader.readLine()`. That's fast enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a BufferedReader since it is made to read faster than something like just the InputStream.

```
String filePath = ".../.../file.txt";
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(pathPath)));
String line = null;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(line);
in.close();  //very important to close streams
```

You would also need try catches.  You could also try a Scanner but I do not think it is as fast as a BufferedReader.

Answer (score -1):

Java 1.4+ includes the new *nio* (New Input/Output) package for faster file transfer and retrieval. Consider taking a look at a similar answer: [Java NIO FileChannel versus FileOutputstream performance / usefulness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605332/java-nio-filechannel-versus-fileoutputstream-performance-usefulness) or the official examples from the Oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/example/index.html